# Dwarf Fortress Iron

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a new fortress that is coming along great. I have a axedwarf squad set up and armed with copper. I found a small vein of one stone that is used for smelting into iron. I don't think that the vein I found will be enough. I need to find more, so my axe-dwarves can get real armor and weapons. Any advice?

Comment: See the answer here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/65677/11199

Answer (score 1):

As the commented possible duplicate mostly focuses on mining, that is not the only source of iron. Two alternatives are:

1. [Goblinite](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Goblinite), smelt down the left over weapons and armor from goblin (invader) attacks.
2. Traders, traders sometimes bring lots of weapons, armor and other items made from iron. Can smelt these down after trading for them or obtaining them in other unmentionable ways.

Answer (score -2):

You can mine around some more until you find another vein. You could also trade for iron, steel, etc. with a caravan.